# using new BigQuery UI to link to an external project

Tags: google-bigquery

This [page](https://isb-cancer-genomics-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sections/progapi/bigqueryGUI/LinkingBigQueryToIsb-cgcProject.html) shows how to use the classic BigQuery UI to link to an external project.  Can this be done with the new UI?

EDIT: To be more explicit, the new UI has a "pinning a project" functionality which seems to allow the user only to choose from their own list of projects, whereas the "classic" UI allows the user to Switch to Project > Display Project and then enter *any* project name, not just one that they have a membership role in.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 4):

There are some limitations for the new BQ UI listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui).

And one mentions what you asked:

Also note that the BigQuery public datasets are not displayed by default in the BigQuery web UI. To open the public datasets, enter the following URL in your browser.

> https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&page=project

Once you've opened the project, pin it.

Comment: Thanks, in fact the solution works for other public projects by substituting a known project name after the p=